# Change HTML of tabpanel created by xtype (Ext.js 4.2)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tabpanel created by the following code inside Ext.container.ViewPort,
how can I change the html dynamically?

```
region: 'center',
xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
id:'contentpanel',
activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
items: {
     title: 'Default Tab',
     html: 'The first tab\'s content. Others may be added dynamically'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is e.g.:

```
items: {
     title: 'Default Tab',
     itemId: 'tab1',
     html: 'The first tab\'s content. Others may be added dynamically'
}
```

then in an event you can change the html of a tab using:

```
...
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#tab1')[0].setHtml('new content');
...
```